# Non-trigonometric Proof for values of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-functions

I'm looking for non-trigometric (also, purely *real* analysis) proofs for the following facts. (For reference, I'm working with the series definitions for sine and cosine.)

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})= \cos(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{1}{2}$.

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})= \sin(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

I've proven the values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ at $0, \pi, \frac{\pi}{2}, 2\pi $and $
\frac{\pi}{4}$ as well as the the standard summation / double-angle formulas. But I'm still having trouble. My only strategy so far has been to write something like the following and perhaps expand out with the summation formulas.

$\cos(2(\frac{\pi}{3})+\frac{\pi}{3})= \cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(2(\frac{\pi}{3})+\frac{\pi}{3})=\sin(\pi)=0$.

Since I obviously don't know the value of these functions at $\frac{\pi}{3}$, I'm not sure if this will get me anywhere.
Could someone explain to me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you use $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} = (e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}})^3= (\cos \frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{6})^3$?

Comment: @ClementC. No, this is strictly real-variable analysis.

Comment: can you use trigonometric relations such as $\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$?

Comment: @Arnaldo Yes, absolutely

Comment: @Rohan I'm looking for a purely analytic proof

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of $\pi$, too. According to your definition, have you already proved that $\sin(\pi)=0$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, I have. Definition is $2\inf \{x>0 : \cos(x)=0\}$.

Comment: @CuriousKid7: all right, then to actually use Novati's solution you just need to prove the addition and duplication formulas through the series definition, that is pretty standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

from $\cos(2(\frac{\pi}{3})+\frac{\pi}{3})= \cos(\pi)=-1$, using summation and double-angle formulas we have:
$$
\left(2\cos^2(\pi/3)-1 \right)\cos(\pi/3)-2\left(1-\cos^2(\pi/3)\right)\cos(\pi/3)+1=0
$$
that for $\cos(\pi/3)=y$ becomes:
$$
4y^3-3y+1=(y+1)(2y-1)^2=0
$$

Comment: This is really neat and actually makes a lot of the results about algebraic trigonometric values make sense.